# Generating XML file including Table attribute LENGTH and TYPE

Tags: c#, xml

I received an XML file with the structure as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHIFT-JIS" standalone="true"?>
<海外生産管理ファイル>
    <PO番号>SV00039</PO番号>
    <データベース>
        <PO>
            <Tbl_PO_H PO番号="SV00039">
                <DATA>
                    <PO番号 LENGTH="13" TYPE="200">SV00039</PO番号>
                    <PO発行日 LENGTH="10" TYPE="200">2017/09/04</PO発行日>
                </DATA>
            </Tbl_PO_H>
            <Tbl_PO_M PO番号="SV00039">
                <DATA>
                    <PO番号 LENGTH="13" TYPE="200">SV00039</PO番号>
                    <PO行 LENGTH="4" TYPE="3">1</PO行>
                </DATA>
            </Tbl_PO_M>
        </PO>
    </データベース>
</海外生産管理ファイル>
```

But when I generate it with the following code :

```
private void generateXML(string fileName)
{
            DataTable dth,dtm;
            var xPONo = txtPONo.Text;
            var _POPreNo = Mid(txtPONo.Text.Trim().ToUpper(), 3, 1);

            if (!IsAllDigits(_POPreNo))
            {
                dth = get_DataforXML_HXX(txtPONo.Text);
                dtm = get_DataforXML_MXX(txtPONo.Text);                
            }
            else
            {
                dth = get_DataforXML_H(txtPONo.Text);
                dtm = get_DataforXML_M(txtPONo.Text);
            }         

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "SHIFT-JIS", "yes");
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

            doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

            XmlElement rootNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "海外生産管理ファイル", string.Empty);
            doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

            XmlElement PONodeRoot = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "PO番号", string.Empty);
            XmlText txtPONOx = doc.CreateTextNode(xPONo);
            PONodeRoot.AppendChild(txtPONOx);
            rootNode.AppendChild(PONodeRoot);

            XmlElement databaseNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "データベース", string.Empty);
            rootNode.AppendChild(databaseNode);

            XmlElement PONode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "PO", string.Empty);
            databaseNode.AppendChild(PONode);

            XmlElement Tbl_PO_HNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Tbl_PO_H", string.Empty);
            XmlAttribute Tbl_PO_HNodeAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("PO番号");
            Tbl_PO_HNodeAttribute.Value = xPONo;
            Tbl_PO_HNode.Attributes.Append(Tbl_PO_HNodeAttribute);
            PONode.AppendChild(Tbl_PO_HNode);

            for (int i = 0; i < dth.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement DATAHNodex = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "DATA", string.Empty);
                Tbl_PO_HNode.AppendChild(DATAHNodex);

                for (int l = 0; l < dth.Columns.Count; l++)
                {
                    XmlElement POHChildNodex =
                        doc.CreateElement(dth.Columns[l].ToString().Trim());
                    POHChildNodex.InnerText = dth.Rows[i][l].ToString().Trim();
                    DATAHNodex.AppendChild(POHChildNodex);
                }
            }

            XmlElement Tbl_PO_MNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Tbl_PO_M", string.Empty);
            XmlAttribute Tbl_PO_MNodeAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("PO番号");
            Tbl_PO_MNodeAttribute.Value = xPONo;
            Tbl_PO_MNode.Attributes.Append(Tbl_PO_MNodeAttribute);
            PONode.AppendChild(Tbl_PO_MNode);
            // ***********************************************************************
            for (int i = 0; i < dtm.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement DATAMNodex = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "DATA", string.Empty);
                Tbl_PO_MNode.AppendChild(DATAMNodex);
                for (int l = 0; l < dtm.Columns.Count; l++)
                {
                    XmlElement POMChildNodex =
                        doc.CreateElement(dtm.Columns[l].ToString().Trim());

                    POMChildNodex.InnerText = dtm.Rows[i][l].ToString().Trim();
                    DATAMNodex.AppendChild(POMChildNodex);
                }
            }
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            doc.Save(fileName);
        }
```

I can only get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHIFT-JIS" standalone="true"?>
<海外生産管理ファイル>
    <PO番号>SV00039</PO番号>
    <データベース>
        <PO>
            <Tbl_PO_H PO番号="SV00039">
                <DATA>
                    <PO番号>SV00039</PO番号>
                    <PO発行日>2017/09/04</PO発行日>
                </DATA>
            </Tbl_PO_H>
            <Tbl_PO_M PO番号="SV00039">
                <DATA>
                    <PO番号>SV00039</PO番号>
                    <PO行>1</PO行>
                </DATA>
            </Tbl_PO_M>
        </PO>
    </データベース>
</海外生産管理ファイル>
```

The output result has not got the attribute LENGTH and TYPE.

But we need it for some special case.

So, my question is how to generate XML file with the above structure (including LENGTH and TYPE )?

Please help. Thanks a lot!
Another related with this post at: [Get the SQL table column schema with Datatype and Max Length in number value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596465/get-the-sql-table-column-schema-with-datatype-and-max-length-in-number-value)

Comment: You are appending the attribute to wrong node : PONode.AppendChild(Tbl_PO_MNode);  Should be DATAMNodex.AppendChild(Tbl_PO_MNode);

Comment: It is OK, I can import this XML to sql table again without error. But my problem is this XML will distribute to many countries and each country has different database structure. So we must need 02 attribute LENGTH and TYPE. Old program was developed by VB 6.0 and the developer  retired a long time ago. So I need to develop it by C#. ANyone help me?

Comment: I can help.  Send me link to where code is located.  Done a lot of conversions from VB to c#.  VB 6.0 was released in 2006 just before Microsoft combined all the langues (c++, c#, and VB) into a single Net 3.0 library when XP was released in 2007.

Comment: The problem is I have not got the source code to analyze it. I rewrite almost part of this program into C# , but I stuck at this XML structure. I think it is related  to Table column schema.Something like this: select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH       
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table_A'

Comment: Does program use a database like Excel or Access?  Oledb can get schema from the database.  Here is VB code : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309488/how-to-retrieve-schema-information-by-using-getoledbschematable-and-vi  Here is c# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections

Comment: Program use SQL server database, but the version is different from each country (for example : 2000, 2008,2012,2016). So we need specify the LENGHT and TYPE in XML file structure

Comment: SQL server is backwards compatible between 2008, 2012, and 2016.  I haven't had to modify any queries when going from 2008, to 2012, to 2016.  I haven't used 2000 so I not familiar with difference.  The country differences are handled with the Culture Info properties.  So once you set Culture in c# the formatting of string will be set like DateTime and Decimal Points.

Comment: using T-SQL with Postgre sql , MySQL,.... It is a little problem too. My main purpose is XML file exported from 01 RMDBS can use with other one.

Comment: The real issue is with the culture conversions and not necessarily the database.