# Get the SQL table column schema with Datatype and Max Length in number value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

I have a Table_A with the column Name and Data Type as below:

```
QUANTITY    int
PO_NO       varchar(13)
FLG         char(1)
AMOUNT       money
```

I want to make the query that return the result like this:

```
QUANTITY    TYPE="3"    LENGHT="4"
PO_NO       TYPE="200"  LENGHT="13"
FLG         TYPE="129"  LENGHT="1"
AMOUNT      TYPE="6"    LENGTH="8"
```

I use this query to get column schema, but the result is not same as my expectation

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH       
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table_A'
```

Results:

```
COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  
QUANTITY    int         NULL
PO_NO       varchar     13
FLG         char        1
AMOUNT      money       NULL
```

So , my question is: How to know the data type int is equivalent to Type=3 and length =4  and so on.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Please se my post at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586370/generating-xml-file-including-table-attribute-length-and-type?noredirect=1#comment86199812_49586370

Comment: The length in your desired result is not the table schema but the physical bytes SQL Server uses to store the data. ISO SQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views return the logical schema, not the physical implementation. You can get the desired result using catalog views like `sys.columns`  together with mapping SQL types to ADO types codes. Why do you care about the physical length in bytes of the data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the fact that  int, mother and other  not string data type have fidex  defined  length  you cant find a proper value in column CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
if you need  you could remap ths with a CASE WHEN

```
select COLUMN_NAME
        , DATA_TYPE
        , CASE DATA_TYPE 
            WHEN 'int' THEN 4 
            WHEN 'money' THEN 8  
            ELSE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
          END
        , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH       
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table_A'
```

Comment: But I need the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH too. I have not found any book about SQL Server that can explain to me why Data Type : money  has Type=6 and Lenght=8 and so on. I want to understand this to make the XML file from the SQL table

Comment: I think I will use your solution with some modification to suit my project when export table to XML file , this file will be import into many kind of RDBMS